# How do I loop through custom posts within the same loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to PHP. So please bear with me. In a WordPress theme, I've created a Custom Post Type (team) and now I want to display 3 post titles in one div, followed by the content of each of the 3 posts (in a different div), then repeat this for every set of 3 posts until the Query ends.

My HTML would look something like this, but I don't know how to assemble the PHP. So any help would be appreciated:

```
<div class="section-wrapper">
    <div class="member-row row-1">
        <div class="team-member member-1">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="team-member member-2">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="team-member member-3">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="summary summary-1">
        <?php 
        // display the_content() of each of the 3 posts I just queried
        the_content(); 
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section-wrapper">
    <div class="member-row row-2">
        <div class="team-member member-4">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="team-member member-5">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="team-member member-6">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="summary summary-2">
        <?php 
        // display the_content() of each of the 3 posts I just queried
        the_content(); 
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mdamia I inherited this (http://pastebin.com/WiiuvbCK). It loops through the posts, but I don't know how to break out of the loop, create my summary div, and then start the loop again.

Comment: Here is some required reading - actually you should read the entire page for context, but specifically the part about nested loops: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Nested_Loops

Comment: @JoshLaBau thanks! So I added a nested loop inside my current loop and it appears to be working. Sort of. But now instead of displaying the same 3 items as in the main loop, it displays a different 3. I also get the feeling I'm repeating my query arguments unnecessarily. Here's my updated code: http://pastebin.com/gCQ5n3y8

Comment: So I'm looking at your target HTML, and I think what you really want is to have a single WP_Query, but within that loop save the results of each post's content to an array. Then, every third iteration, output your summary div and the section/member-row markup, and destroy the array holding the content. The summary content will therefore only show for the preceding three items in each loop.

Comment: @JoshLaBau that's correct, but I have absolutely no idea how to do it. Any pointers? Thanks for your help.

Comment: My advice would depend on your current level of knowledge. How much programming have you done before this?

Comment: @JoshLaBau I understand the basics. If you can give me a general idea I should be able to figure it out.

Comment: In these situations I find it helpful to simply write out the logical structure in English. Here's about how it should go: http://pastebin.com/LRn1cUcg. You should be able to code that out using existing elements and Google even if you are getting to know the basics. I hope it helps!

Comment: @JoshLaBau that actually makes perfect sense. I'm pretty sure I can stumble my way through. Thanks so much!

Comment: You bet! If you run into specific implementation questions, post them as new questions. The more specific your problem, the more likely you are to get a direct answer around here :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try an easier html but if you want to use that one you can use this code.

```
 <div class="section-wrapper">
<?php
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'team',
    // choose other differentiating parameter, for example tag 
    'tag'                     => 'main'
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The loop
if( $query->have_posts() ): while( $query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); 
?>
<div class="member-row row-1 <?php post_class(); ?>">
    <div class="team-member member-1">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </div>
</div>
<?php

endwhile; endif;

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>

<?php
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'team',
    // choose other differentiating parameter, for example tag 
    'tag'                     => 'main'
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The loop
if( $query->have_posts() ): while( $query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); 
?>


<div class="summary <?php post_class() ?>">
    <?php 
    // display the_content() of each of the 3 posts I just queried
    the_content(); 
    ?>
</div>

<?php

endwhile; endif;

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
</div>


<div class="section-wrapper">
<?php
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'team',
    // choose other differentiating parameter, for example tag 
    'tag'                     => 'seconday'
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The loop
if( $query->have_posts() ): while( $query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); 
?>
<div class="member-row row-1 <?php post_class(); ?>">
    <div class="team-member member-1">
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </div>
</div>
<?php

endwhile; endif;

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>

<?php
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'team',
    // choose other differentiating parameter, for example tag 
    'tag'                     => 'secondary'
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The loop
if( $query->have_posts() ): while( $query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); 
?>


<div class="summary <?php post_class() ?>">
    <?php 
    // display the_content() of each of the 3 posts I just queried
    the_content(); 
    ?>
</div>

<?php

endwhile; endif;

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
</div>
```